# Content-Security-Policy with NONCE and Sub Resource Integrity

Tags: javascript, security, http-headers, content-security-policy

I am exploring ways in which I could/should use CSP and SRI for my website.

For my site I'm looking to use a CSP, something like this.

```
Content-Security-Policy:
block-all-mixed-content;
base-uri https://www.example.com;
default-src 'self';
object-src 'none';
script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-RandomValue' 'unsafe-inline' https:;
report-uri https://www.example.com/report;
```

NOTE: I used recommendations as per https://www.websec.be/blog/cspstrictdynamic/ so don't give me a hard time about the 'unsafe-inline' directive or not using whitelisted uri's.

My site also uses Sub Resource Integrity checks for all externally sourced scripts, so I am thinking that I probably should also include the CSP directive.

```
Content-Security-Policy: require-sri-for script
```

My site also contains some inline scripts (which is why I want to use the CSP random nonce but means I have to use it for all ).

Does it make sense to use SRI as well as implementing CSP random nonce?
And if not then what is a good practice?

Comment: To clarify: You say your site is **already** performing SRI checks by some method. Is that CSP SRI, but only for external resources, or another method? Would the use of CSP SRI double the integrity checking for those resources?

Comment: Yes the site is already performin SRI for resources like so - <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-AIodEDkC8V/bHBkfyxzolUMw57jeQ9CauwhVW6YJ9CA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: My understanding is that the directive 'require-sri-for script' simply enforces the use of SRI for all scripts, so there is no doubleing up. If I'm am wrong can someone clarify?